# How to limit checked in OnMultiChoiceClickListener

Tags: android, dialog

I'm developing an Android app which has Dialog with MultiChoiceItems.
I'd like to limit the checked numbers 3 outof 10 choice.
I wonder when I tap 4th checkbox, cannot check with toast alert is the best way.
Could you help me to realize this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
 DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener MeasuresDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {


           if(isChecked) 
            {
              selectedMeasures.add(AvailableMeasures[which]);

                    if(selectedMeasures.size() > 3)
                      {
                         //display toast saying that only three items can be checked.
                           selectedMeasures.remove(AvailableMeasures[which]);
                      }
            }
          else
            {
              selectedMeasures.remove(AvailableMeasures[which]);
            } 
         }
       };
```

Here selectedMeasures is an ob of type ArryaList which can be used to store selected values.

Comment: Yes,that's fine. THank you all!

Comment: Happy to help. Also note that, If you have got the required answer for your question from someone in stackoverflow, then you should accept it as answer.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I'm new here but I've understood with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an increment to Flag count each time a check box is checked and than on every Check you will have to check the Flag count.

Comment: Yes, I can count isChecked each time, but I can't find how to prevent checking more than 3 as the checkboxes are still clickable more than 3. How can I control this? Thanks!